# Spy and verifyCallOf message processors for flow-ref in munit

Tags: mule, munit

Can a spy or verifyCallOf message processors be used on flow-ref? We have a flow as follows:

```
<flow name="myMainFlow">
    ........
    ........
    <flow-ref name="mySubFlow" />
</flow>

<sub-flow>
    ...
</sub-flow>
```

I am unable to use spy or verifyCallOf on flow-ref calls. But I am able to use them on the message processors inside sub-flow. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you post your munit code thats trying to verify? You don't spy/verify or mock the `flow-ref` element itself. You need to do it on the flow or sub-flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mock the FLOW or sub flow not the flow-ref

https://github.com/mulesoft/munit/blob/munit-3.5.x/munit-integration-tests/src/test/munit/mp-mocking-test.xml#L321

https://github.com/mulesoft/munit/blob/munit-3.5.x/munit-integration-tests/src/test/munit/mp-mocking-test.xml#L338